# spring boot @EnableConfigurationProperties mark internal class happen exception

Tags: java, spring-boot

spring 5.1.9-RELEASE
spring boot 2.1.7-RELEASE
when i has internal class to register ,i use @EnableConfigurationProperties marks on class A and B ,at this time has happen exception; i remove the class A annotation;at this time started successful;
the class B use @EnableConfigurationProperties registering C,at this time B is also registered,the classB should b be registered at this time ?
But when I move the two internal classes to the same path as TestConfiguration, both class A and class B have to be @EnableConfigurationProperties annotated to complete the startup

```
package com.test.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.test.configuration.TestConfiguration.TestConfigB;

import lombok.Data;

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(TestConfigB.class)
public class TestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(TestConfigA.class)
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "test-a", name = "enable", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
    public TestConfigA testConfigA(TestConfigB testConfigB) {
        return new TestConfigA();
    }

    @Data
    public class TestConfigA {
        private String name;
    }

    @Data
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test-b")
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(TestConfigC.class)
    public class TestConfigB {
        private String applicationId;

        @Autowired
        TestConfigC axxcConfig;

        public String getApplicationId() {
            if (applicationId == null) {
                applicationId = axxcConfig.getApplicationId();
            }
            return applicationId;
        }
    }

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test-c")
    public class TestConfigC implements ApplicationContextAware {
        private String applicationId;
        private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

        public String getApplicationId() {
            if (applicationId == null) {
                applicationId = applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty("spring.application.name");
            }
            return applicationId;
        }

        @Override
        public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
            this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: By the way, _always include the actual error_, not just "an error". It helps make your question searchable for other people, and it's not usually the case that you will find an expert who can identify the problem merely by looking at the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your `@ConfigurationProperties` classes need to be `static` so that copies of them can be created independently of (before) the containing configuration class.

Comment: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationPropertiesImportSelector.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanRegistrar.register(BeanDefinitionRegistry, ConfigurableListableBeanFactory, Class<?>)

Comment: i think the outer class repeat register the class B ,It's caused autowired the Bean TestConfigB happen exception